# Delete a node from a given position in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I want to delete a node from a given position in a list,
but my delete function is not working.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
Node* Delete(Node *head, int position)
{
  int count=0;
  Node* temp, *temp1, *temp2;
  temp = head  ;
if(head==NULL){
    return 0;
    }
else if(position == 0)
    {

    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
    return head;
}
  else{
      while(count!= position-1)
         {
         temp = temp->next;
         count++;   
     }
     temp1 = temp->next;
     temp->next = temp1->next;

     free(temp1);
     return temp;
 }

return head;
}
```

Comment: *How* is it not working? Do you get build errors? Crashes? Have you tried running in a debugger? Stepping through the code line by line to see where it does wrong?

Comment: Please define desired behavior. What should the return value be?

Comment: My guess: `return temp;` should be removed.

Comment: thanks a lot MikeCAT...i removed "return temp; " from code...and now its working fine...:)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, format your code properly.

Then, remove `return temp;` so that the former part of list won't be lost.

You can also remove first `return head;` because the function will do `return head;`  in the last part anyway.

```
Node* Delete(Node *head, int position)
{
  int count=0;
  Node *temp, *temp1, *temp2;
  temp = head;
  if(head==NULL){
    return NULL;
  }
  else if(position == 0)
  {
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
  }
  else{
    while(count!= position-1)
    {
      temp = temp->next;
      count++;
    }
    temp1 = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp1->next;

    free(temp1);
  }

  return head;
}
```

Note that `return 0;` is valid because `0` is a null pointer constant ([N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.3.2.3 Pointers) and converting it to a pointer is defined, but using `NULL` is better because it will make it clear that it is dealing with a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `return temp;` with `return head;` 
Also include the logic to handle if there are nodes less than position.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add to MikeCAT's answer. You should also handle the condition when the number of nodes are less than the position.

One of the ways of doing this could be:

`while(count!= position-1)
    {
      temp = temp->next;
      if(temp == NULL)
        return head;
      count++;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return temp` and write `return head`.
Moreover, check for the condition if the position is greater than the number of nodes in the linked list.
Also before freeing the pointer I would suggest to add `temp1->next=NULL` and then `free(temp1)`.